# How to fix incompatible types in this struct/linked-list script?

Tags: c, struct, types, linked-list

I'm working on a script to create a linked-list of words (locals) from a file in C. Basically, I want a linked list of the first word of each line. 
I'm getting the error "incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct local *' from type 't_local {aka struct local}'" and can't figure out what's happening. Help would be very appreciated as I'm struggling a bit with linked lists

```
typedef struct local{
    char *name;
    struct local *next;

}t_local;


void crialistalocais(t_local *header){
    FILE *fp;
    t_local *aux = header->next;
    char line[150];
    char *name1;
    fp = fopen("loclss.txt","r");

    while (!feof(fp)){
        fgets(line, 100, fp);
        namel = strtok(line, '/');
        aux->name = namel;
        aux->next = *header;
        header=aux;
    }

}
```

Comment: `header` is a `struct local *`, therefore `*header` is a `struct local`.

Comment: (Also, your loop should not check `feof`, but the return value of `fgets` like so: `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) ...`

Comment: You are doing a lot of dangerous stuff here. Where are you allocating memory for your linked list items? You are also reusing the line buffer, pointing struct members at it without copying any of the data.

Comment: Hey @Cheatah ! Thanks for the constructive criticism! Any tips on how to fix it? It's my first time having to deal with memory allocation and this type of structures, so any help would be amazing

Answer (score 3):

```c
aux->next = *header;
```

You're dereferencing `header` and trying to assign a `struct local` to a `struct local*`.